# array_map() vs preg_replace(). Что быстрее?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Я новичок в программировании, прошу не судить строго...

Есть массив `$files` с большим количеством названий файлов в качестве значений элементов этого массива. Мне нужно добавить к каждому значению путь к директории проекта (плагина), который сохранен в константе `PUGIN_DIR`.

Задача не сложная, вижу 2 рабочих способа, как это сделать:

**1. array_map()**

```
$files = array_map( function( $str ) {
    return PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $str;
}, $files );
```

**2. preg_replace()**

```
$files = preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . '$1', $files);
```

Вопрос: Что быстрее?

Comment: засеки время до и после выполнения

Comment: вы и правда думаете, что конкатенация строк может быть медленнее чем регулярка? при том, что preg_replace внутри делает тот же цикл, что и array_map. Быстрее и эффективнее будет скорее сделать array_walk, чтобы не создавать копию массива. Но я тоже не вижу смысла дописывать это дело в массив. подставляйте по месту использования. и добавьте разделитель директорий в конец при определении константы.

Comment: @teran Спасибо. Короче регулярка. array_walk не подойдет, т.к. нужно именно переписать массив. Зачем держать пути в массиве? Не знаю. Это вордпресс ) Они изначально в массиве, в обрезанном виде. Лежат в мускуле. Оттуда и беру этот массив. Просто работаю с тем что есть. Мне нужно взять несколько подобных массивов с путями (обрезанными и нет), и отфильтровать их (название, расширение, убрать несуществующие, и т.д.). Затем из них оставить те, файлы которых содержат определенные строки. Затем те, которые подключают те, которые содержат эти строки... Затем подключить массив(!) к шаблону фильтром...

Comment: `array_walk` прекрасно изменяет значения массива, если параметры получать по ссылке

Answer (score 0):

Ты уже потратил на решение этой задачи больше времени, чем та виртуальная разница в скорости, которую ты здесь ищешь, сэкономит тебе за миллион лет работы этого скрипта.

Если тебя интересует снижение скорости обработки массивов, то надо смотреть не на функцию обработки массива, а в первую очередь на осмысленность задачи. В данном случае очень сомнительно, что пути требуются именно в массиве, а не могут быть добавлены при использовании конкретного элемента